# How to intensify and edit glass caustics?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, lighting, shadows, glass, caustics

I am having trouble with my caustics - using 3.2 and they work fine. However they do not do the trick just right - I need the shadow of the glass to have much more of the light streaks, following the shape of object. Does anyone know how to intensify caustics? Add new light streaks onto the shadow?

I am attaching a picture of my result and of reference of how I need it to look like.

Thank you in advance for help[image]